# Cell Fracture Keeps Exploding When Another Object Is Set To Passive Animated

Tags: cycles-render-engine

So I've been experimenting with the Cell Fracture add on and it was going okay, but then here's what happened. I subdivided a cube about five times, used the add on (if it helps, the material value is one and the margin one is 0.0000), I made one cell active with start deactivation checked and everything is working fine. I add an icosphere, place it above the cells, set it to active with a heavier weight, and it works. Everything is fine. So here is where my problem occurs...

I added in a mesh (Godzilla, if you must know) and set it to passive. I animated it walking through the cells so it looks like it's getting destroyed. Nothing happens. I make sure to set the collision shape to mesh and then I check "Animated" since it's animated. Now suddenly the cells are starting to get destroyed the second the simulation starts, even though I checked "Deactivation < Start Deactivated". It's so weird, because when I turn off "animated", it goes back to working fine as if the cells need something that is active to hit it. Is this a bug? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Guess I found out what I needed to do! Just make it *Active* and *Animated*!